# Keycloak X509TrustManager implementation

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, keycloak, activemq-artemis

I have integrated Keycloak and ActiveMQ Artemis. Both are running on HTTPS. I have added the Keycloak truststore in ActiveMQ Artemis. Now I am getting this error in ActiveMQ. As the error says there is `no X509TrustManager Available`. Can someone help me how to implement this in Keycloak v21.0.

```java
2023-05-20 07:53:53,100 WARN  [org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment] Failed to load URLs from https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8443/realms/artemis-keycloak-demo/.well-known/openid-configuration
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1318) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1195) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1138) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:570) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:119) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:554) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:114) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getOidcConfiguration(KeycloakDeployment.java:230) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.resolveUrls(KeycloakDeployment.java:182) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getJwksUrl(KeycloakDeployment.java:281) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.sendRequest(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:98) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.getPublicKey(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:63) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.getPublicKey(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:121) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:111) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.AbstractKeycloakLoginModule.bearerAuth(AbstractKeycloakLoginModule.java:205) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.BearerTokenLoginModule.doAuth(BearerTokenLoginModule.java:37) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.AbstractKeycloakLoginModule.login(AbstractKeycloakLoginModule.java:127) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-20.0.5.jar:20.0.5]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:754) ~[?:?]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:678) ~[?:?]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:676) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714) ~[?:?]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:676) ~[?:?]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) ~[?:?]
    at io.hawt.system.Authenticator.login(Authenticator.java:215) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at io.hawt.system.Authenticator.doAuthenticate(Authenticator.java:178) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at io.hawt.system.Authenticator.authenticate(Authenticator.java:151) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:79) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:43) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:43) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:43) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:43) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:43) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:43) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:43) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.filters.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:43) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at io.hawt.web.auth.SessionExpiryFilter.process(SessionExpiryFilter.java:107) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at io.hawt.web.auth.SessionExpiryFilter.doFilter(SessionExpiryFilter.java:60) ~[hawtio-system-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.component.JolokiaFilter.doFilter(JolokiaFilter.java:50) ~[artemis-web-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578) ~[jetty-security-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1571) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1378) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484) ~[jetty-servlet-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1544) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1300) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:51) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:562) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282) ~[jetty-server-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:319) ~[jetty-io-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100) ~[jetty-io-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53) ~[jetty-io-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:412) ~[jetty-util-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:381) ~[jetty-util-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:268) ~[jetty-util-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:138) ~[jetty-util-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:407) ~[jetty-util-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894) ~[jetty-util-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038) ~[jetty-util-10.0.11.jar:10.0.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1621) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1302) ~[?:?]
    ... 112 more
2023-05-20 07:53:53,102 WARN  [io.hawt.system.Authenticator] Login failed due to: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "this.input" is null
```

I went through [X.509 Client Certificate User Authentication](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_x509) on how to do the same, but could not get it.
Or is there something else that I am missing?

Java Version - openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18 LTS

I have added all the configurations I am using to spin up ActiveMQ Artemis and Keycloak. Added the keystore.jks and truststore.jks as well. [subhidh/activemq-keycloak](https://github.com/subhidh/activemq-keycloak)

[DEBUG SSH, HANDSHAKE OUTPUT](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subhidh/activemq-keycloak/main/debug_output.log)

In debug output I see this

````java
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|23|qtp404588697-50|2023-06-02 10:10:40.254 IST|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.unwrap(SslConnection.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)}

)```
````

Comment: I suspect your keystore/truststore file or password are invalid, could you validate them with keytool?

Comment: I checked the keystore/truststore using ```keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_file```. And also replicated the scenario locally. Created keystore/truststore using this [commands](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled#jms-ssl-example). Still having the same issue

Comment: Are you using an absolute path to set `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`?

Comment: Yes, Using an absolute path.

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino I have added the ActiveMQ configuration and command to spin up Keycloak. Added the GitHub URL above in the question. Please, I request you to have a look.

Comment: Could you try setting the trust store type, i.e. `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12`?

Comment: Magically ```.p12``` is working but ```.jks``` is not.

Comment: Does .p12 work without '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12'?

Comment: Yes, it is working without '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12'

Comment: Since Java 9, the default keystore format is PKCS12, maybe this is why you don't need `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12` fr your `.p12` file, Did you tried `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks` with your `.jks` file?

Comment: Yes, when using .jks I used ```Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks```, but this didn't help.